# JButton style same as words in a text

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, settext

I want to make a java application, that will contain some text. I want some of these words to act like buttons. My idea is to put all the text in a text panel and the words that I want to act like buttons to be buttons. But i cant get a button to have the same style as the text. The button its always lower than the text from that line. It's possible to fix that ?
Ty.

Example:

John went to the shop.

"shop" is a button and can be clicked, and it looks exactly like the other words.

My problem:
I can't find how to make a JButton look like the other words.

Comment: "words to act like buttons" -- `JButtons` usually have text in them anyways. You specify it in the constructor. Also, please provide the code you have so far.

Comment: when i say words to act like buttons means this, I have a sentance:
John went to shop and bought a new book.
I want that "shop" to be a button, but I want to look exactly like the others words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just add a mouse listener to your JLabel with your text. That would respond to a mouse click action. You could also had a hover listener to change the border to give your user some indication that the text is clickable and remove the border when you are no longer hovering.

```
  final JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Click Me!");
  lblNewLabel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
     @Override
     public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0)
     {
        System.out.println("Label Clicked!");
     }
     @Override
     public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
     {
        lblNewLabel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(1));
     }
     @Override
     public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) 
     {
        lblNewLabel.setBorder(null);
     }
  });
```